# Remote Mediator loads only the first page

Tags: api, kotlin, android-room

I'm trying to add offline capabilities to my TMDB app. I've tried doing it with `Room` but `RemoteMediator` only loads the first page.
This is how I implemented the `RemoteMediator class`

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagingApi::class)
class MoviesPopularMediator(
    private val service: ApiService,
    private val database: PopularMoviesDatabase
) : RemoteMediator<Int, MoviesModel>() {
    override suspend fun load(
        loadType: LoadType,
        state: PagingState<Int, MoviesModel>
    ): MediatorResult {
        return try {
            val loadKey = when(loadType){
                LoadType.REFRESH -> {
                    1
                }
                LoadType.PREPEND -> return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = true)
                LoadType.APPEND ->{
                    state.lastItemOrNull()
                        ?: return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = true)
                    getMoviesPage()
                }
            }
            val response = service.getPopular(
                page = state.config.pageSize,
            )
            val listing = response.body()
            val results = listing?.results
            if (listing != null) {
                database.withTransaction {
                    if (loadKey != null) {
                        database.popularMoviesPageDao().savePopularMoviesPage(MoviesPage(page = listing.page, results = listing.results, total_pages = listing.total_pages))
                    }
                    if (results != null) {
                        database.popularMoviesDao().savePopularMovies(results)
                    }
                }

            }
            MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = response.body()?.page == response.body()?.total_pages)

        } catch (exception: IOException) {
            MediatorResult.Error(exception)
        } catch (exception: HttpException) {
            MediatorResult.Error(exception)
        }

    }

    private suspend fun getMoviesPage(): MoviesPage? {
        return database.popularMoviesPageDao().getPopularMoviesPage().firstOrNull()

    }
}
```

I get the data from this api: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/`.

Any ideas on how I should change this `RemoteMediator` so that it will load all pages?

If you need more details please feel free to ask

Comment: I faced the same issue and i'm still facing the same issue , did you get to solve the issues , it never called LoadType.Append , therefore no more paged are pushed into room !

Comment: Can't remember, I was doing this project for an internship but I didn't had enough time to finish this functionality. So the answer is no